# How to pull {category_url_title} from related content

Tags: categories, matrix, playa, category-group

Wondering how I can pull {category_url_title} back from a Matrix field `{recipes-related}` that uses PLAYA related entries for `{left}` and `{right}`. I have this but doesn't pull the Category URL Title back so that I can build up the url.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{recipes_channel}" category_group="1" url_title="{last_segment}" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
    {recipes-related}
        {left}
            <a href="{path="{channel_url}/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">
        {/left}
        {right}
            <a href="{path="{channel_url}/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">
        {/right}
    {/recipes-related}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: How is this question Low Seg2Cat-related?

Comment: Hi Low, I've removed seg2cat from the questions as it's more to do with not being able to pull back the {category_url_title} from a related entry.

Answer (score 0):

`{category_url_title}` is only defined within the `{categories}{/categories}` tag pair variable (or within an `{exp:channel:categories}` tag pair).

In your left / right sample code you don't open the `{categories}` tag pair before trying to retrieve the `{category_url_title}`, and so it fails.

In your second bit of code you explicitly open a `{categories}` tag pair, which explains why you get the `{category_url_title}` returned.

Perhaps something like this is what you need:

```
{left}
    <a href="{path="{channel_url}/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">
{/left}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Yeah so as soon as I put this inside the {left} it doesn't work. Move it outside them and it works. Hmm!